# git cannot detect new files in android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git, github

I'm collaborating on an android app development using GitHub and I'm using eclipse adt bundle for the development. The problem is, git does not detect any new files which I add to the repo in the res or drawable folder although it is detecting any changes I make to the existing Java or xml code. It detects any new Java files I create but it does not detect any new xml file or any new png files which I put in the layout or drawable folder.
I've shown my gitignore file to my project manager and other colleagues and they said it has no error, the problem is local.

Comment: try `git check-ignore -n -v <file>`.

Comment: Tried this..after executing this command it says something like this: .gitignore:42:res    RSP/res/drawable-xhdpi/filename.png   What does this mean? is gitignore causing this problem?

Comment: Problem solved..but i dont know how. After running the above command, I opened my gitignore file and just commented out the line number shown in the output of that command. then did a git status and everything was shown.

Comment: @Ishtiaque if you could resolve the issue please add the solution add accept it , so that people know it's closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
git check-ignore -n -v <file>
```

To see if the file has been explicitly configured to be ignored by Git.

If that prints out something .gitignore:XX, then you know the line number of the Rule in the .gitignore file that is causing the problem.

Typically, .gitignore is used to exclude build output like *.o, but it may also be excluding binary objects, or anything else.

How to 'fix' the problem depends on your particular situation.  You can have a .gitignore file in each directory of your project.  In some cases you might want to remove a rule from the root .gitignore file, but in others you might want to create a lower level .gitignore and undo an earlier rule for just one particular directory.

[The Git Docs have a pretty good description of it along with examples](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html)

Comment: This solved my problem. My res folder was being ignored. Just commented out that line and my new files are being now detected. Thank you @Andrew C

Answer (score 0):

There's another option beside `gitignore` to check files which is at `.git/info/exclude` .Check it please.

Comment: Yeah..checked this file...nothing there except for a few default comments.